# Complement inversion

Tags: meaning, grammar, inversion

What's the meaning of `Mushrooms it is`? What is this grammar structure and inversion? Please include a grammar source and some more examples.

**Arlene**: would you like to go to a movie tonight?
**Jim**: I'd rather stay home and watch T.V.
**Arlene**: Sounds good. Maybe we could make dinner later.
**Jim**: I'd rather not cook tonight. Let's order out for some pizza. We haven't done that for a while.
**Arlene**: OK. Mushrooms or anchovies?
**Jim**: I'm in the mood for pepperoni. Let's get a pepperoni pizza.
**Arlene**: I'd rather not. Pepperoni gives me heartburn. I'd rather have mushrooms than pepperoni, if that’s OK with you.
**Jim**: Mushrooms it is! Now. What should we watch on TV? How about the new Stephen King thriller?

**[SOURCE](http://pablolivas.uanl.mx/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Laboratorio-Ingl%C3%A9s-4-3ra-y-5ta.pdf)**

Comment: The inversion is just for emphasis: this explains the 'it' bit. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73815/why-it-s-turtles-not-they-are-turtles/73821#73821

Answer (score 2):

"Mushrooms it is"  = it is mushrooms we are having, it is decided, it is agreed.

Colloquial use, unaware of any mention in grammar books.
Enlighten me anyone  :)

Comment: Your sense of the meaning is correct. The inversion puts emphasis on the word appearing in the unusual spot. In context, the emphasis is an affirmation of the choice.

Answer (score 2):

The conventional wording would be, "It is mushrooms". That is, "The selected topping is mushrooms". We sometimes switch the sentence around -- "Mushrooms it is!" -- to emphasize the object.

Note that unlike languages that put endings on words to indicate their role in the sentence, English primarily determines role by word order. For example, "Al punched Bob" and "Bob punched Al" mean two very different things. So there are sharp limits on your ability to show emphasis or delay revealing a key word by changing word order. But there are possibilities, like here.